# Getting coordinates of a map's corners

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I want to get coordinates of map's corners like shown in the image

[image]

Comment: I want to know why you are voting down at my question?!

Comment: Weird. It's possible people thought you meant screen coordinates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map.getBounds()`.  This returns a LatLngBounds object.  From that you can then use `getNorthEast()` and `getSouthWest()` to get those corners.  These aren't the ones you want though, so you'll have to do a little bit of logic to figure out the North West and South East parts.  i.e. use the `lat()` of the NorthEast corner with the `lon()` of the SouthWest corner for the NorthWest coordinate, and the `lon()` of the NorthEast corner with the `lat()` of the SouthWest corner for the SouthEast coordinate.